# Anyone know how to do a List<string> case insensitve comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net

say I have a list of names

```
var names = new List<string>{"Tom", "Dick", "Harry"};
```

Now say I want to search for Tom.

```
names.Contains("Tom");
```

Not a problem but what say I want to find with a different casing say "tOM".

Can anyone tell me how to do this without creating another class?

I have a solution where I have a Comparer class with inherits from `IEqualityComparer`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the overload of [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) that takes an IEqualityComparer, and pass in [StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase(VS.80).aspx) or [StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase(v=VS.80).aspx).

```
names.Contains("tOm", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this to check for any case arrangement for the name.

```
bool hasTom = names.Any(x => x.Equals("tOM", 
                               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This will ensure that you list and the input aren't checked with case sensitivity. More on [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) for `String.Compare()` and `String.Equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a List? HashSet has a constructor overload that can take an equality comparer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
names.Exists(n=> n.ToLower() == ("tOM").ToLower())
```

Comment: the docs say, a `ToUpper()` is faster than a `ToLower()` and a `StringComparison.xxxIgnoreCase` is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the best way to do this is:

names.Any(n=> n.ToLowerInvariant() == "Tom".ToLowerInvariant())

The function return a boolean and will check for all items in a non-capital version, non matter of the culture.